# Adding a new USB PCI card 

Tags: installation, usb, pci

I'm completely new to Ubuntu. I've installed Xubuntu 11 on an old machine quite successfully and plugged a wireless dongle into one of its on board USB1.1 ports, giving me wireless internet without too much trouble.

I've now bought a USB 2.0 PCI card and installed it, hoping that it would be picked up automatically on boot and I could connect via USB2.0. Unfortunately I think it's not being recognised.

I have the following outputs from `lsusb` and `lspci`:

`lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 050d:705a Belkin Components F5D7050 Wireless G Adapter v3000 [Ralink RT2573]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`sudo lspci -v`

```
00:0e.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB (rev 43) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: NEC Corporation Hama USB 2.0 CardBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2

00:0e.1 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB (rev 43) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: NEC Corporation Hama USB 2.0 CardBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ec800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2

00:0e.2 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB 2.0 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: NEC Corporation USB 2.0
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 9
    Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
```

Can anyone please suggest how I can overcome this problem? Automatic detect/configure tools would be best, but I'm prepared to edit config files if necessary. A Google on 'linux + install new hardware' wasn't too illuminating, I apologize if this has been asked before.

**Update**

Doing a  dmesg | grep ehci, gives a 'startup error -19' entry and 'USB bus 1 deregistered'. Googling for the 1st error gives lots of hits all related to problems with USB 2.0 and the kernel in 10.10. maybe it's still a kernel problem with 11.04

Comment: As a side note, there are some boards in which specific PCI slots can be disabled on BIOS. Its a good idea to check that first. I spent some hours thinking my board was not being properly recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Your latest update looks interesting "Doing a dmesg | grep ehci, gives a 'startup error -19' entry and 'USB bus 1 deregistered'. " - I had a similar issue when adding PCI cards.

I found a couple of issues - I had ran out of IRQs - i.e. I had added too many cards - I pulled all cards that could use multiple IRQs e.g. firewire and these sort of error messages in dmesg stopped.

I also had to turn off USB Legacy Support in the BIOS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's something to do with IRQs too. I thought I'd tried legacy off in the Bios, but I'm going to try again to make sure

Answer (score 0):

From your second listing log, it looks like your USB 2.0 was properly detected. It says

```
  "USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB 2.0 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])"
```

That sounds good to me. Have you tried connecting something simple as a USB disk on it ? Usually, USB 2.0 extra cards are picked up automatically, and you will not necessarily get a big notification saying "New Hardware detected" as you would under Windows.

Comment: I've tried it with a memory stick, a flatbed scanner and the wireless dongle with no luck. Sometimes if I start with a device plugged into the new 2.0 card, the lsusb just hangs, even CTRL z won't get it out.

Comment: in that case sounds like the card is bad or not installed correctly. Reseat it.

Comment: @Broam - the card is physically installed OK, it's detected as a PCI device. It's just not registered by the O/S as a USB device. See my update

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like answering my own questions, but as it's now fixed, I'll state what I did.

I moved the card from PCI slot 3 to slot 4. That's it - I've no idea why it worked but it did

Comment: by moving from slot 3 to 4 you have changed the IRQs given to your card.  I suspect you may have fixed this issue for this card, but one of your other cards may start to give you an issue (as per my answer) - anyway good luck.

Comment: @fossfreedom - I'm sure you're right, even though the bios had 'auto' for the IRQ on all the cards. As the other cards are an old dial up modem and a sound card that both came with the original (windows ME) machine, neither of which I use, I don't care much if they are bust. Thanks for your help though. I'm just glad I've got a usable Linux box now for less than £20 (wireless dongle, 512MB RAM and the USB2.0 card). It's great being a cheapskate! Lots to learn though.

Comment: I'd pull the modem. If it isn't useful to you, it's hogging resources. Normally I wouldn't care, but you've been having issues - get rid of extraneous stuff.